# Mapping JSON objects with incremental names to C# models

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

What is the best way to map a JSON object that has a structure whereby it contains a list of objects whose names are dynamically created through incrementation?

e.g.

```
{"data":
 {
  "object-0":[{"id":"1","name":"John"},{"id":"2","name":"Mary"}],
  "object-1":[{"id":"3","name":"Gary"},{"id":"4","name":"Mark"}]
 }
}
```

Comment: looks like a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<T>>` to me - do you have `T` defined?

Comment: Maybe a `Dictionary<string, Users>` where string/key refers to `"object-o"` and `User` refers to the object. There's lots of ways to do this though.

Comment: Dictionary<string, user[2]> would suit you - if you always going to have 2 users in there

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've got a class like

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You could deserialize this into a `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<User>>` like so

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<User>> values =
    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<User>>>(json);
```

This also assumes the use of [json.net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

Comment: incremental logic of filling the initial array assumes that later it's gonna be used rather via index/looping than via key access. So I don't find dictionary suiting this case. Maybe List of Lists is a better option?

Comment: @KonstantinChernov I don't agree with either of you, for the given scenario he should be using Dictionary<string, User[2]>

Comment: *incremental logic of filling the initial array* - which initial array? I feel his json sample was exactly that - a sample.

Comment: @Mathematics I think *should* sounds a bit too strong in your assumption as we don't know details of how this array was obtained/how it's gonna be used later...

Comment: the incremental nature of the keys in his sample also suggest the contrary of what you're saying @KonstantinChernov - they are indexable keys! object-0, object-1, object-2 etc...

Comment: @Alex incremental is the keyword here imo, so downvoted anyway

Comment: @KonstantinChernov There's no need for sarcasm, it's not welcome here on stackoverflow.

Comment: @KonstantinChernov incremental - ie, unique. ie... indexable!

Comment: @Alex why IEnumerable why not fixed array or hash set ?

Comment: I guess more the question *why fixed array?* - if the OP only ever has 2 in the array, then sure, a fixed array would be fine, but why back yourself into a corner?

Comment: You cannot put the array length in the type declaration, thus `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, User[2]>>(json);` will not compile.  Array length is not a property of type.  You could do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, User[]>>(json);` or `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, List<User>>>(json);`

Comment: ... or even `Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<User>>` as per my answer!!!

I totally forgot about `User[2]` not being compilable!

Comment: @Alex - true.  Though If you deserialize to `IEnumerable<T>` with Json.NET I believe it actually allocates a `List<T>` under the covers.

Comment: @dbc you confirmed what I was thinking about - thanks for that, however Alex not many people care about performance down to memory level these days as it's negligible BUT still best practice is to use types that are closer to your goals. Most junior developers make mistakes in declaring types and they end up with a big mess. Thinking about future which may never come in real

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Json.NET](http://json.net) library to transform any JSON string to arbitrary dynamic object in .NET. This should do:

```
dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
```

In your case I suppose you need `object-0`, `object-1` etc in a list/array (since they are incrementally generated by the looks of it) and not as typed properties as such, in which case you can trivially transform the obtained dynamic object to whatever you want. For an e.g.

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public Dictionary<string, List<User>> Objects { get; set; }
}

string jsonString = '...';
dynamic jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);

// could have made use of LINQ to shorten this bit of code 
// but unfortunately dynamic doesn't play well with extension methods
var data = new Data { Objects = new Dictionary<string, List<User>>() };
foreach (var obj in jsonObject.data) 
    data.Objects[obj.Name] = obj.Value.ToObject<List<User>>();

// now you have everything in `data` instance.
```

To replicate the exact json structure, you can have a root class to hold the data. Something like:

```
class Root { public Data data { get; set; } }
var root = new Root { data = data };
```

If you need the entire user objects in one flat structure, you can flatten it too:

```
var users = data.Objects.SelectMany(kv => kv.Value);
```